# Show that $E\left[\left\vert\sum y_kx_k\right\vert^4\right]\le3E\left[\left\vert\sum y_kx_k\right\vert^2\right]^2$ for $(x_k)$ i.i.d. random signs

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, expectation

$x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4,\,\ldots\,,x_m$ are either positive or minus signs and they are random and independent; $y_1, y_2, y_3, y_4, \ldots,y_m \in \mathbb{R}$.

Prove the following:

$$E\left[ \Bigl|\sum_{k=1}^m y_k\, x_k\Bigr|^4 \right] \leq 3 E \left[ \Bigl| \sum_{k=1}^m y_k\, x_k \Bigr |^2 \right]^2 $$

Is there any sort of expected value basic properties i can use here to prove this? The above equation IMO looks like $E\left[ E[y_k] \right]$ so am I proving that $E\left[ {E[y_k]}^4 \right] \leq 3E\left[ {E[ y_k ]}^2 \right]^2$?

Comment: So you mean $\Pr\{X_i = -1\} = \Pr\{X_i = 1\} = 1/2$?

Comment: yes thats exactly what i meant

Comment: plz halp thanks; any hint would be appreciated

Comment: Hint: Expand the LHS and watch all the terms whose expectation is zero disappear. Now, which terms are left?

Comment: @LeeDavidChungLin Using `\Bigl` and `\Bigr` is almost always a bad idea.

Comment: @Did For a long time that's what I thought. I actually just learned last year that it is often better than the \left --\right combination, and it is better than just \big. The reason for the former is that automatic sizing can be wrong sometimes, and the reason for the latter is that \bigl and \bigr combo provides proper spacing.

Comment: @LeeDavidChungLin Who told you so? `\Big` has predefinite size, which can be optimal or not, while `\left` and `\right` are supposed to go for the optimal size.

Comment: @Did I'm not sure if this is the right place to have this discussion. But anyway, the automatic sizing is [less than optimal](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/173771/119235) more [often than I used to believe.](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/1234/119235). After learning that, I can personally attest that those issues are very true, in addition to the occasional [random posts online](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/154925).

Comment: @Did Having said that, when doing Mathjax on StackExchange I personally adapt slightly different principles from how I properly do LaTeX. Seriously the same code doesn't produce the same result on the webpage. I often do feel very uncomfortable due to not being able to typeset properly like with a compiler. Indeed I sometimes feel I'm forced to "bend to rules" just to make things look similar to a nice document with good codes.

Comment: @Did The bottom line: my opinion is that mathjax is a useful tool for interactive webpages, however, when it comes to coding (LaTeXing) it necessarily has to be operated on a different (lower) standard.